# How to get client's country address Ip address using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to get client Ip address , country details using javascript json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **ipapi.co** api:

```js
// https://ipapi.co/json/

 $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/json/', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks dinesh ghule... thanks a lot you saved my time

Comment: one thing it is not giving actual data.

Comment: can you add your output here

Comment: {
  "ip": "69.172.201.153",
  "isp": "Cogeco Peer 1",
  "org": "DosArrest",
  "hostname": "69.172.201.153",
  "longitude": "-118.257",
  "latitude": "34.0473",
  "postal_code": "90017",
  "city": "Los Angeles (Central LA)",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "continent_code": "NA",
  "region": "California",
  "district": "Los Angeles County",
  "timezone_name": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "connection_type": "",
  "asn": "",
  "currency_code": "USD",
  "currency_name": "US Dollar",
  "success": true,
  "cached": true
}

Comment: I'm in United Arab Emirates

Comment: you can use other api to get city by IP address info

Comment: this is not free@DineshGhule

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't provide such functionality. Usual solution is to make an endpoint on you server which returns IP address and query it in XHR request from a page.

Comment: yes, my website is secured with ssl. I'm getting error while taking get data from json

Comment: That's very strange. Usually it comes from misconfiguration or invalid CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Use some webservice that can return json

**jsonip.com**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('http://jsonip.com', function (res) {
        $('p').html('IP Address is: ' + res.ip);
    });
});
```

**Smart-IP.net** (leading one today)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?', function(data) {
        $('p').html('My IP Address is: ' + data.host);
    });
});
```